# How to change the value of the drop-down on change event?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have two drop-down lists which are from same table. One contains employee code and second one contains employee name. If I change the employee code then other drop-down should show the employee name relevant to code and if I change the employee name then it should show the code. I am able to successfully retrieve the values but I am unable to show value in the drop-down. Following is my code:

```
$("select#code").on("change", function () {
         getNameFunc($(this).val())
});

$("select#empName").on("change", function () {
         getCodeFunc($(this).val())
});

function getNameFunc(value) {
   $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getName", "Employees")',
        data: { id: value },
        cache: false,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
               $("#empName").val(data.Name);
        }
    });
}

function getCodeFunc(value) {
     $.ajax({
          url: '@Url.Action("getCode", "Employees")',
          data: { id: value },
          cache: false,
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
               $("#code").val(data.Code);
          }
    });
}
```

My drop-down list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("EmpCode", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "code" })
@Html.DropDownList("EmpName", null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "empName" })
```

In alert function, I am getting expected value but the problem is displaying it in to drop-down list.

Comment: When the page load , are you load your drop down value OR dynamically load the dropdown value with one dropdown change.

Comment: I am loading drop-down using ViewBag.

Comment: Post the both dropdown

Comment: If that dropdown menu is dynamically created then you should try to console.log the element if it finds it.

Comment: In `console.log` I am getting Employee Name but I am unable to set the value of the drop-down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple , Try it , Let me assume selects render as , this is dummy test , best approch you must save value = EmpID

Emp Name dropdown

```
<select id="name">
<option value="EmpID1"> Name 1 </option>
<option value="EmpID2"> Name 2 </option>
</select>
```

Emp Code dropdown

```
<select id="code">
 <option value="EmpID1"> Code 1 </option>
 <option value="EmpID2"> Code 2 </option>
 </select>
```

Inside your ajax , if you want change/load name front the of the dropdown then

**Value set by value**

```
  $('#name').val(data.EmpID1)

Similarly reverse

$('#code').val(data.EmpID1)
```

**Value set by text / name**

```
$('#name option:selected').text(data.Name)
```

Comment: Show your ajax methods (two ajax method in your case) & two dropdown input field

Comment: What type of error you getting ? let me know your process how are you doing

Comment: I am not getting any error. The problem is value is not appearing in the drop down because both of them are dynamically generated.

Comment: That is the matter dynamically generated dropdwn,, i 'll update my answer

Comment: Yes, both the drop down are dynamically generated.

Comment: Try   $('#name').val(data.EmpID1).trigger('change')  OR   $('#name').val(data.EmpID1).change();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146350/discussion-between-armaan-labib-and-asif-raza).

Answer (score 0):

Check this code. You might get help from this.
Note that I have not implemented ajax call in this code.

```js
$("#emp_code").on("change",function(){
    $("#emp_name").val($("#emp_code").val());
});

$("#emp_name").on("change",function(){
    $("#emp_code").val($("#emp_name").val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Emp Code:</label>
<select id="emp_code">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br/>
<label>Emp Name:</label>
<select id="emp_name">
  <option value="1">ABC</option>
  <option value="2">XYZ</option>
  <option value="3">PQR</option>
  <option value="4">JKL</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Have you checked values of both dropdown i.e. employee code and employee name? They must be same.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand you. Same Means? I have updated my question please look it again.

Comment: Lets say you have 5 employees with ids 11,12,13,14 and 15 then your both dropdowns i.e. employee code and employee name must have the value attribute i.e <option value="1"> as value = "11" , value = "12" till value = "15
"